# Why bagging algorithm doesn't influence bias

Tags: machine-learning, variance, bias, bagging

I am learning the bagging algorithm and I have realized that bagging can reduce the variance, but I am confused when I read that bagging doesn't influence the bias.

Here is a picture in the slides of a course about bagging. This plot the decision boundary of bagging 25 Pocket models, and the max iteration for each Pocket algorithm is 1000 (Pocket is a modified Perceptron Learning Algorithm). I think the single Pocket model cannot get zero training error if the data is not linear-separable, but bagging can achieve the zero training error by combine 25 Pocket models. So I think bagging can reduce the bias. Is there anything wrong in my deduction? Thank you for any help!

[image: Using bagging algorithm]

Comment: i thought bagging will increase the bias...

Comment: If you think I am wrong, please tell me whether I misunderstood the graph, or the graph is not correct?

Comment: Generally speaking, bagging will reduce variance but will tend to slightly increase bias. The most usual  situation gives you a trade-off favourable to bagging, because the reductoon of variance helps the model to generalize better